# Вырезать часть кода HTML в CefSharp Wpf

Tags: c#, html

Я использую браузер CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWeb для загрузки веб-страницы.

Я могу получить исходный код:

```
private void WebBrowserLoad(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                homeWeb.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml =>
                {
                    var html = taskHtml.Result;
                });
            }
        }
```

xaml: `<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="homeWeb" Address="anika-co.ru" Grid.Row="1" Initialized="profile_Initialized"></cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser>`

Мне нужно вырезать 'header', как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Пример приведите.

Comment: Например, на сайте https://anika-co.ru/ есть шапка с id "globalheader", нужно при загрузке страницы в WPF вырезать эту самую "шапку".

Comment: напишите скрипт на JavaScript и выполните его в браузере

Comment: aepot, да спасибо так лучше всего работает)